# RGB image captured by Intel realsense camera is dark (using python code)

Tags: python, rgb, intel, realsense

I am using the python code below to take RGB image using Intel realsense (D 435i) camera. The image captured by the python code is dark. However, the image is not dark when I use the camera's SDK. How can I take image with the same quality as the image captured by the camera's SDK?

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import math

pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()

config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 1280, 720, rs.format.z16, 30)
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 1280, 720, rs.format.bgr8, 30)

profile = pipeline.start(config)
depth_sensor = profile.get_device().first_depth_sensor()
depth_scale = depth_sensor.get_depth_scale()

# We will be removing the background of objects more than
#  clipping_distance_in_meters meters away
clipping_distance_in_meters = 1.5 
clipping_distance = clipping_distance_in_meters / depth_scale


align_to = rs.stream.color
align = rs.align(align_to)

frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()

aligned_frames = align.process(frames)
aligned_depth_frame = aligned_frames.get_depth_frame()
color_frame = aligned_frames.get_color_frame()

depth_image = np.asanyarray(aligned_depth_frame.get_data())
color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())


# Remove background - Set pixels further than clipping_distance to grey
grey_color = 153
depth_image_3d = np.dstack((depth_image,depth_image,depth_image)) #depth image is 1 channel, color is 3 channels
bg_removed = np.where((depth_image_3d > clipping_distance) | (depth_image_3d <= 0), grey_color, color_image)

# Render images
depth_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image, alpha=0.03), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
images = np.hstack((bg_removed, depth_colormap))
cv2.namedWindow('Align Example', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

# Filename 
path = 'C:/Users/aatefi2/Desktop/Intel real sense/Codes/'
imageName1 = str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")) +  '_Color.jpg'
imageName2 = str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")) +  '_Depth.jpg'
imageName3 = str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")) +  '_bg_removed.jpg'
imageName4 = str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")) +  '_ColorDepth.jpg'
imageName5 = str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")) +  '_DepthColormap.jpg'

# Saving the image 
cv2.imwrite(imageName1, color_image) 
cv2.imwrite(imageName2, depth_image) 
cv2.imwrite(imageName3, images) 
cv2.imwrite(imageName4, bg_removed )
cv2.imwrite(imageName5, depth_colormap )

key = cv2.waitKey(1)
# Press esc or 'q' to close the image window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

pipeline.stop()
```

Answer (score 4):

I added the code below to change the exposure time manually (https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/4449). The images (captured by this manual setting) are brighter than the ones captured by auto-exposure setting.

```
# The code to set exposure time manually#

profile = pipeline.start(config)


# Get the sensor once at the beginning. (Sensor index: 1)
sensor = pipeline.get_active_profile().get_device().query_sensors()[1]


# Set the exposure anytime during the operation
sensor.set_option(rs.option.exposure, 156.000)
```